# GNOME Boxes: VM gets paused when going back to home screen

Tags: gnome, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, gnome-boxes

I'm using gnome-boxes to run an Ubuntu VM (Arch Linux host).
From the home screen of GB (where all the VMs are shown) I click on the VM's thumbnail and it opens and takes all GB window.
Everything works fine, I can put GB on another virtual desktop and also minimize it. My VM keeps running in background for days…
But if from GB I click the back button to go back to the home screen (where all my VM thumbnails are) after a few seconds my VM seems to go into sleep and I cannot reach it anymore (has bridged networking) from my host system.
I have to click on the VM thumbnail again to resume it.
Is this normal? And what can I do if I want to run two VMs at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, It was easier than expected... vm properties > system tab > execute in background > on :)